# Syncing Project View with Editor in RubyMine

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

This should be obvious, but I can't see how to do it. Just want the project browser to stay in sync with the current file I'm editing.

I'm using IdeaVIM plugin in case that's causing any issues, though I think it's just default value *not* to sync.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Project view** has an option to **Autoscroll from Source** under the **Gear** icon. If you prefer manual sync, use `Navigate` | `Select In...` menu or the corresponding keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

The manual sync can be found in `Navigate | Select In...` The keyboard shortcut would be `ALT-F1 1 ESC` (the '1' selects the project windows, the ESC goes back to the editor window).